# what's wrong with my jquery tab code?

Tags: jquery

the following code that i referenced form the internet, but it doesn't work. why?

jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".tab:not(:first)").hide();
        $(".tab:first").show();

        $(".htabs a").click(function(){

         var stringref = $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];

          $(".tab:not(#"+ stringref +')').hide();

          //fix 
          if(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3)=="6.0"){

            $('.tab #'+stringref).show();
          }else{
            $("tab #"+stringref).fadeIn();
                return false;
          }
        });
```

html code:

```
<ul class="htabs hide">
        <li><h2><a href="#design">Graphic design</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="#development">Development</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="#freebies">Freebies</a></h2></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tabs">
        <div id="design" class="tab">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">TYpography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TYpoface</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">painting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Optical balance</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>


        <div id="development" class="tab">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">TYpography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TYpoface</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">painting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Optical balance</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>


        <div id="freebies" class="tab">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">TYpography</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TYpoface</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">painting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Optical balance</a></li>
            </ul>           
        </div>



    </div>


$(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];  what't the meaning of this line? why it's one( [1])?
```

Comment: What doesn't work with it? A script error? something doesn't display? You need to provide some information about what isn't working

Comment: $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]; Means split the href at a '#' which returns an array containing [0] => '' and [1] => 'design'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on these two lines:

```
$('.tab #'+stringref).show();
```

and

```
$(".tab #"+stringref).fadeIn();
```

The `.tab` should be removed from both, so you have:

```
$('#'+stringref).show();
```

and

```
$("#"+stringref).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Also, if you posted all your javascript there you are missing the closing to `$(document).ready(function(){` and you need to add a `});` to the bottom.

Comment: you're right. thank you. but when i used this $('.tab #'+stringref).show(); when i click the tab. it not show the content. while $('.tab#'+stringref).show(); it can work,the last is that there is no space between .tab and #. why?

Comment: `'.tab #designtail'` looks for an element with the class tab and then searches it's children and grandchildren etc. for an element with id detail. Whereas `'.tab#design'` searches for an element which has both the class tab and the id detail. Since Id's are unique though, all you need is `'#design'`

Comment: got it. many thanks.PaulPRO. i am still understand this line well. $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]; i knows it gets the current a label's attribute and split of the # sign. but i don't know why add [1]?

Comment: split() is an ordinary javascript function, not jQuery and it returs an array. In this case the array has two elements [0] which will always be '' in your code, and [1] which contains the rest of the string after #. try playing with split() here: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/nUrAz/ to see what it alerts in different situations :)

Comment: Split returns an array of strings. Since you know that the information you are after lies after the # you are interested in the "2nd" item in this array, hence [1] (zero based counting).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what isn't working...you do have a dot missing on one line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".tab:not(:first)").hide();
$(".tab:first").show();

$(".htabs a").click(function(){

 var stringref = $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];

  $(".tab:not(#"+ stringref +')').hide();

  //fix 
  if(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3)=="6.0"){

    $('.tab #'+stringref).show();
  }else{
    //$("tab #"+stringref).fadeIn(); // Missing a . on this line
    $(".tab #"+stringref).fadeIn(); // Added the .
        return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: you're right. thank you. what's the meaning of this line? $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1]; i know it gets the a label's attribute. and get rid of the #. but i don't know [1] this part meaning?

Answer (score 1):

> $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];  what't the meaning of this line? why it's one( [1])?

This is within a function bound to the click event of an anchor element, so this refers to the that element. So the code takes the value of the href attribute of the anchor element, splits is by the '#' sign, and then takes the part after the # sign. 
The code wasn't working because of bad selectors in if-else part

```
$(".tab:not(:first)").hide();
    $(".tab:first").show();

    $(".htabs a").click(function(){

     var stringref = $(this).attr("href").split("#")[1];

      $("div.tab:not(#"+ stringref +')').hide();

      //fix 
      if(jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version.substr(0,3)=="6.0"){

        $('#'+stringref).show(); //fixed selector
      }else{
        $("#"+stringref).fadeIn(); //fixed selector
      }
      return false;
    });
```

Comment: why i can't use this $(this).attr("href").split("#")?

Comment: because split will return an array of 2 elements. The first is an empty string, the second is whatever is after #. So you used [1] to get the second element of the array.